# how to make an array from an object?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

i have this object, each key contains an index after the underscore at the end of it, so i can  do something and try to gather each one with the same index together and get the expected obj, i don't know how to do it with underscore of even plain java-script

```
var obj = {
        phoneNumber_0 : "2",
        phoneNumber_1 : "0",
        phoneType_0 : "Home",
        phoneType_1 : "Work"
}


var expected = [
  {number: '2', type: 'home'},
  {number: '0', type: 'work'},
]
```

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What does "gather each one with the same index together and get the expected obj" mean? What is the "expected obj"?

Answer (score 2):

You could split the keys of the object for the name and for index. Then build a new object if necessary and assign the value of the actual property.

```js
var object = { phoneNumber_0: "2", phoneNumber_1: "0", phoneType_0: "Home", phoneType_1: "Work" },
    result = [];

Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
    var p = k.split('_');
    result[p[1]] = result[p[1]] || {};
    result[p[1]][p[0]] = object[k];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will do what you have been looking for,

```js
var obj = {
        phoneNumber_0 : "2",
        phoneNumber_1 : "0",
        phoneType_0 : "Home",
        phoneType_1 : "Work"
}
var finalArray = []
Object.keys(obj).map((key,index) => {
  if (obj['phoneNumber_' + index] || obj['phoneType_' + index])
  finalArray.push({ number: obj['phoneNumber_' + index], type:obj['phoneType_' + index]})
})

console.log(finalArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be your expected result

```
var obj = {
  phoneNumber_0 : "2",
  phoneNumber_1 : "0",
  phoneType_0 : "Home",
  phoneType_1 : "Work"
}

var expected = []
for(var key in obj){
  if(key.indexOf('phoneNumber_') === 0){
    var kn = key.replace('phoneNumber_', '')
    expected.push({number: obj[key], type: (obj['phoneType_' + kn]||'').toLowerCase()})
  }
}

console.log(expected)
```